# How to annotate each segment of a stacked bar chart

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart, stacked-bar-chart

[image]

I've been trying to annotate each sub-amount of a stacked bar chart with its values like the picture shown above (values not accurate, just an example).

```
df.iloc[1:].T.plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
plt.show()
```

Data frame that I used:
[image]

The linked post is somewhat similar to my question but I do not understand the code given in that answer nor were there any explanations given.

[Annotating Values in Stacked Bar Chart Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48922328/annotating-values-in-stacked-bar-chart-matplotlib)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Imports and DataFrame

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = {'var': ['TR', 'AC', 'F&B'], '2019 1Q': [6600, 1256, 588], '2019 2Q': [6566, 1309, 586], '2019 3Q': [7383, 1525, 673]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.set_index('var', inplace=True)

# display(df)
     2019 1Q  2019 2Q  2019 3Q
var                           
TR      6600     6566     7383
AC      1256     1309     1525
F&B      588      586      673
```

### Update as of `matplotlib v3.4.2`

- Use [`matplotlib.pyplot.bar_label`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar_label.html)
- See [How to add value labels on a bar chart](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67561982/7758804) for additional details and examples with `.bar_label`.
- Tested with `pandas v1.2.4`, which is using `matplotlib` as the plot engine.

```py
ax = df.T.plot.bar(stacked=True, figsize=(6, 5), rot=0)

for c in ax.containers:
    ax.bar_label(c, label_type='center')
    
ax.legend(title='Categories', bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc='upper left')
```

[image]

### Original Answer - prior to `matplotlib v3.4.2`

- [Transpose](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transpose.html) the dataframe and then use [`pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.bar.html) with `stacked=True`.
- An `ndarray` is returned with one [`matplotlib.axes.Axes`](https://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes) per column with `subplots=True`.

  - In the case of this figure, `ax.patches` contains 9 [`matplotlib.patches.Rectangle`](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Rectangle.html) objects, one for each segment of each bar.

    - By using the associated methods for this object, the `height`, `width`, `x`, and `y` locations can be extracted, and used to annotate the rectangles.
- The difference this question has from [How to annotate a stacked bar chart with word count and column name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62239435/how-to-annotate-a-stacked-bar-chart-with-word-count-and-column-name) is the other question needs to extract and use alternate text for labels, and this dataframe needed to be transposed.

```py
ax = df.T.plot.bar(stacked=True)
plt.legend(title='Categories', bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc='upper left')

for i, rect in enumerate(ax.patches):
    # Find where everything is located
    height = rect.get_height()
    width = rect.get_width()
    x = rect.get_x()
    y = rect.get_y()

    # The height of the bar is the count value and can used as the label
    label_text = f'{height:.0f}'

    label_x = x + width / 2
    label_y = y + height / 2

    # don't include label if it's equivalently 0
    if height > 0.001:
        ax.text(label_x, label_y, label_text, ha='center', va='center', fontsize=8)
```

[image]

Comment: So much easier with the Matplotlib 3.4.2 update.